# Skybound GeckoFX set host field

Tags: c#, http, geckofx

For debugging I need to manipulate the host-field in HTTP-Request of the GeckoFX Webbrowser control. Does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it. You have to set an additional header and than the host-header will be replaced.
Example:

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(urlTB.Text, Skybound.Gecko.GeckoLoadFlags.None, 
                          referrerTB.Text, null, string.Format("Host: {0}\r\n",
                          hostTB.Text));
```